# why chrome dev tool insert extra div in body

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, tags, devtools

i'm doing test a demo file which contains a single h1 tag. But whenever I inspect the page in chrome, it shows me an extra div(containing multiuple div tag) at the bottom of the body
[image: dev tools screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at your browser plugins, it sounds like you have some webcam addon that might be inserting that code into DOM for screen-capture purpose or some such. If you check that network request in the dev tools you can find the HTML that was sent from server, and eliminate the possibility that you're creating in server-side